# how to display the content from MySQL table as the row count equals to multiple of 3

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table having many rows and my question is,

How to

i) Display rows from MySQL table as the row length is equal to multiples of 3

ii) In other case if row count not equal to multiples of 3 then display the row equal to nearest multiples of 3
for example, if the row length is 5 then display only first 3 rows.

for more clarification,

1. If mysql_num_rows = 3, display all three rows.
2. If mysql_num_rows = 5, display any three rows.
3. If mysql_num_rows = 11, display any nine rows.

Comment: So get rows count and break while loop if rows left is less then 3?

Comment: @u_mulder : if row length is less than 3 nothing to be displayed. and if the row length is 5 then display any 3 rows.

Comment: row length or row number?..give sample data and view

Comment: @DevLakshman : total items in a table. `mysql_num_rows`

Comment: @u_mulder : check my question again. I have edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
   $res=mysqli_query(
$con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_name");
 $row=mysqli_num_rows($res);//calculating total row count

$lim=$row-$row%3;//deciding limit
$res1=mysqli_query(
$con,"SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT $lim");
//echo '<br>'.$row1=mysqli_num_rows($res1);
while($show=mysqli_fetch_array($res1))
{
    echo '<br>'.$show['id'];
}
```

Execute the query & show your data

Comment: thanks man. It works.

Answer (score -1):

### MySQL Only

```
SELECT (COUNT(*)-(COUNT(*)%3)) FROM tbl_name INTO @lim;

SELECT @rownum := 0;

SELECT t.*, @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rowno FROM tbl_name t WHERE rowno <= @lim;
```

### PHP & MySQL

```
$res=mysqli_query( $conn, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tbl_name");

$rec=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

$lim=$rec["cnt"]-($rec["cnt"]%3);

$res=mysqli_query( $conn, "SELECT * FROM tbl_name LIMIT $lim");
```

You'll need to validate `cnt` and `lim`

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_first_page_products)-((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_first' at line 1`